# Angular form doesn't return binded object

Tags: angular, forms

I'm trying to create an angular form with 2 input fields that upon submission posts the values of the fields to a function that handles them accordingly

I've made sure that the FormsModule and NgForm are imported correctly

```
  <div class="modal-body">

    <form class="example-form" (submit)="createNewPartySubmit(newPartyForm)" #newPartyForm="ngForm">
      <mat-form-field class="input-field" floatLabel="auto">
        <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
        <input matInput name="name" type="text" [ngModel]="newPartyItem?.name" required #name="ngModel" />
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field class="input-field" floatLabel="auto">
        <mat-label>Country</mat-label>
        <input matInput name="country" type="text" [ngModel]="newPartyItem?.country" required #country="ngModel" />
      </mat-form-field>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button mat-button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary primary" (click)="createNewPartySubmit()">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the function handling is as below

```
  createNewPartySubmit(newPartyForm: NgForm) {
    console.log(newPartyForm);
  }
```

the printed output is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the handler `(click)="createNewPartySubmit()"` on the submit button currently. It is passing `undefined`/`null` payload. With button `type="submit"`, clicking the button will by default trigger a submit event, which you have being already handled by `(submit)="createNewPartySubmit(newPartyForm)"` on the `<form>` tag.

Change:

```
<button mat-button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary primary" (click)="createNewPartySubmit()">Submit</button>
```

To:

```
<button mat-button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary primary">Submit</button>
```

This will not only avoid triggering duplicate events (click + submit) as well as avoid passing `undefined`/`null` payload to `createNewPartySubmit`, which is what's happening via this `(click)="createNewPartySubmit()"` handler.

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

In function declaration in form CreateNewPartSubmit($event) try this

Comment: Still, returns undefined

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call the `createNewPartySubmit` method twice, you can remove it from either the `<form ...`> part or from the `click()` listener on the button.

Because you're using the template driven approach, you have to pass the local variable as a parameter for your function, so the createNewPartySubmit should look like `createNewPartySubmit(newPartyForm)`.

And on your `console.log` you should use the `.value` to print what you want.

### html

```html
<form class="example-form" #newPartyForm="ngForm">
  <mat-form-field class="input-field" floatLabel="auto">
    <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
    <input matInput name="name" type="text" [ngModel]="newPartyItem?.name" required #name="ngModel" />
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field class="input-field" floatLabel="auto">
    <mat-label>Country</mat-label>
    <input matInput name="country" type="text" [ngModel]="newPartyItem?.country" required #country="ngModel" />
  </mat-form-field>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button mat-button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary primary" (click)="createNewPartySubmit(newPartyForm)">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

### ts

```js
reateNewPartySubmit(newPartyForm: NgForm) {
    console.log(newPartyForm.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two issue the first that you call the method `createNewPartySubmit` twice.

So change:

```html
<button mat-button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary primary" (click)="createNewPartySubmit()">Submit</button>
```

To:

```html
<button mat-button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary primary">Submit</button>
```

And the other thing change **(submit)** to **(ngSubmit)**:

```html
<form class="example-form" (submit)="createNewPartySubmit(newPartyForm)" #newPartyForm="ngForm">
```

To

```html
<form class="example-form" (ngSubmit)="createNewPartySubmit(newPartyForm)" #newPartyForm="ngForm">
```

I hope that I help you.